# Redirect a logged in user using firebase in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

What I want is that if the user is already signed in, the app should skip the log in page for him and display the main page. 
I tried the below code but it doesn't work. How to overcome this issue ?

```
componentWillMount() {
   let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   if (user != null) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Drawer'); 
   }  
   this.unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Drawer');
   }  
  });  
}
```

Comment: did you research for FLAGS ? it should solve your problem

Comment: no, is it in the manual or a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this hint, it should solve your problem

```
class App extends React.Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          loading: true,
          authenticated: false,
        };
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, authenticated: true });
          } else {
            this.setState({ loading: false, authenticated: false });
          }
        });
      }

      render() {
        if (this.state.loading) return null; // Render loading/splash screen etc

        if (!this.state.authenticated) {
          return <Login />;
        }

        return <Home />;
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, The login page shows up and when submitting the data it goes to the main page, but the issue remains the same which is after clearing the app from the  working application (RAM) it open the login page again. How to open the main page directly?

Comment: Yes it will remove the states stored in the app, you can't do nothing I'd you erase app data and reopen the app, the same concept applied for all the apps , if you delete app data from any social media , if you try to login again it will ask you again for the credentials, one approach should be to store device token in the cloud and state , but  I think it's not necessary since its a long process for just a login

Comment: Ok, Thank you Gastón.